# Comentários em expressões regulares?

Tags: regex, comentários

Expressões Regulares não são fáceis de ler. Há algum jeito de descrever o que cada letrinha faz?

Nessa regex: `\{.*?[^\}]+\}` irá capturar tudo que tiver num campo `{ }` mas há algum jeito explicar ela sem perder funcionalidade?

Eu fiquei curioso pelo motivo de achar essa regex:

```
                                  # Character definitions:
'
(?>                               # disable backtracking
    (?:
    \\[^\r\n]|                    # escaped meta char
    [^'\r\n]                      # Data character except '
    )*
)
'?
|
                                  # Normal string & verbatim strings definitions:
(?<verbatimIdentifier>@)?         # this group matches if it is an verbatim string
""
(?>                               # disable backtracking
    (?:
                                  # match and consume an escaped character including escaped double quote ("") char
    (?(verbatimIdentifier)        # if it is a verbatim string ...
        """"|                     #   then: only match an escaped double quote ("") char
        \\.                       #   else: match an escaped sequence
    )
    |                             # OR

                                  # match Data char except double quote char ("")
    [^""]
    )*
)
""
```

Ela captura uma expressão de *string*, e está descrita pelos comentários procedidos por `#`. É real isso? Os espaços são removidos durante a interpretação da expressão?

Comment: Só uma coisa, o Regex do .NET Framework também suporta isso?

Comment: Melhorei a resposta.

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas se quer apenas o que está entre colchetes, não precisa usar `.*?` na regex, apenas `\{[^\}]+\}` basta: https://regex101.com/r/gWEh0A/2/ :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, estes são comentários para as expressões regulares do C# (ou mais especificamente do .NET, já que ele é válido para todas as linguagens que adotam o .NET como biblioteca). Tudo que está após o `#` até o fim da linha será ignorado. Também é possível determinar o início e fim do comentário com parênteses.

Em outras linguagens ou mais especificamente em outras bibliotecas de expressões regulares os comentários podem estar disponíveis com sintaxe um pouco diferente.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#miscellaneous_constructs).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73581/112052): conforme a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/miscellaneous-constructs-in-regular-expressions#end-of-line-comment), para poder usar esses comentários, você deve habilitar o modo "*ignore pattern white-space*", seja usando a *flag* `(?x)` (também chamado de [*mode modifier*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), ou *inline option*), ou a opção [`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_IgnorePatternWhitespace).

Exemplos:

```
string s = "abc";

// usando (?x), imprime "True"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[a-z]{3}(?x) # começa com 3 letras"));
// usando RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace, imprime "True"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[a-z]{3} # começa com 3 letras", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
// sem nenhuma das opções, não é interpretado como comentário, imprime "False"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[a-z]{3} # começa com 3 letras"));
```

No terceiro caso, como nenhuma das opções (`(?x)` ou `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`) foi usada, o trecho  `# começa com 3 letras` (incluindo o espaço antes do `#`) é considerado parte da regex. Ou seja, nesse caso a regex só encontraria um *match* caso a string fosse `"abc # começa com 3 letras"`.

---

Um detalhe é que esta opção não se limita a habilitar o uso de comentários. Como o próprio nome da opção diz (*ignore pattern white-space*), quando ela está habilitada, a regex ignora os espaços em branco da expressão (e também tabulações e quebras de linha - o que, aliás, permite que se usem os comentários, já que o comentário vai do `#` até o final da linha, e permite que a regex continue na linha seguinte).

E nesse caso, tem uma diferença entre `(?x)` ou `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`: o primeiro pode estar em qualquer lugar da expressão, e só afeta o trecho que aparece depois dele. Já o segundo sempre afeta toda a expressão. Ex:

```
string s = "abc";

// usando (?x), imprime "False"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "a  b(?x)   c"));
// usando RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace, imprime "True"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "a  b   c", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
```

No primeiro caso, o `(?x)` só ignora os espaços antes do `c`. Já os espaços entre `a` e `b` fazem parte da regex, e por isso ela não encontra um *match* e imprime `False`.

No segundo caso, `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` faz com que todos os espaços da regex sejam ignorados, por isso ela encontra um *match* e imprime `True`.

---

Existe ainda uma sintaxe alternativa para que o `(?x)` só afete parte da expressão:

```
string s = "abc";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "a(?x:   b)  c")); // False
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "a(?x)   b   c")); // True
```

No primeiro caso, `(?x:   b)` quer dizer que todos os espaços antes do `b` serão ignorados. Mas os espaços antes do `c` estão fora dos parênteses, então eles fazem parte da regex.

Já no segundo caso, `(?x)` faz com que todos os espaços que estão depois dele sejam ignorados.

Outra opção é usar `(?-x)`, que "desliga" o `(?x)`:

```
string s = "ab c";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "a(?x)   b c")); // False
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "a(?x)   b(?-x) c")); // True
```

No primeiro caso, todos os espaços da regex são ignorados, então ela na verdade está buscando por `abc`. Mas como a string em questão tem um espaço, o resultado é `False`. No segundo caso, o espaço depois do `(?-x)` não é ignorado, já que ele "desliga" o `(?x)`, e por isso o espaço antes do `c` faz parte da regex, e o resultado é `True`.

---

Se quiser que a regex tenha espaços, mesmo com esta opção habilitada, o jeito é usar `[ ]` (uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) contendo um espaço - repare que há um espaço entre os colchetes) ou o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` (lembrando que `\s` [também corresponde a <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)).

---

Para incluir comentários em uma regex, também existe a sintaxe`(?# comentário )`. Nesse caso, não precisa habilitar a opção *ignore pattern white-space*, pois tudo que está entre `(?#` e `)` é ignorado:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc", "ab(?# um comentário)c")); // True
```

Lembrando que, caso tenha um espaço fora do trecho `(?# ... )`, estes fazem parte da regex, e caso queira ignorá-los, aí é necessário habilitar a opção *ignore pattern white-space*:

```
string s = "abc";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "ab(?# um comentário)  c")); // False 
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, "ab(?# um comentário)(?x)  c")); // True
```

---

Este modo também é chamado de [*free spacing mode*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) em algumas *engines*.